# Rss20FeedFormatter is producing RSS that is not well formed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, feed, xml-validation, rss

I am using ASP.Net MVC2 and have a RSS feed for my blog. I am using out of the box functionality in System.ServiceModel.Syndication and Rss20FeedFormatter.

The feed works fine and can be read by Outlook as well as every browser I have tried.  However when I submitted the RSS feed to google as a sitemap I got validation errors.
Out of curiosity I validated the feed with feedvalidator which reported similar issues.

Feed:  http://www.chrispfarrell.com/Blog/Rss

If you pop this feed in at feedvalidator.org you will see the problems.

There is really no custom code going on to generate the RSS.

The controller action is

```
public FeedResult Rss()
        {
            const string baseUrl = "http://www.chrispfarrell.com/Blog/View/";

            var blogs = _blogService.GetBlogs();
            var feed = new SyndicationFeed
                           {
                               Title = new TextSyndicationContent("Chris Farrell"),
                               Copyright = new TextSyndicationContent("Copywrite Chris Farrell 2010")
                           };

            var postItems = blogs.Take(25)
                .Select(p => new SyndicationItem(p.Title,p.Body,new Uri(baseUrl + p.BlogUrl))
                                 {
                                     PublishDate = p.DateCreated,
                                 });

            feed.Items = postItems;
            return new FeedResult(new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed));
        }
```

Any comments as to why the feed would not be valid and well formed?  I can post the code for FeedResult if needed but its pretty standard code.

Thanks

Chris Farrell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feed was missing the <link> element in the root <channel> element.

Rather than using an object initializer, I am using one of the constructors now which accepts 3 arguments(feed title, description and feed alternate link).  The third argument for feed alternate link renders in the root channel <link> tag which makes the feed now valid.